# How can I use object as an array?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

I want to use next syntax:

```
$o = new MyClass();
$o['param'] = 'value'; // set property "param" in "value" for example
```

Now I have an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MyClass as array
```

Can I use object like this? Maybe there are any magic methods?

Comment: why not use $o->param = 'xxx' ?

Comment: Question isn't in it. I want to know can I do it like in my example

Comment: @MarcB Read the answers and you'll know how to do your "apple taste like an orange" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do, is create a new class called MyClass and make it implement the [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

You can then use:

```
$myArray = new MyClass();
$myArray['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Although it's easier to just use:

```
$myArray->foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: Is `ArrayAccess` is a standart PHP interface?

Comment: @Victor Have you read the doc that both answered posted? It says it right there on the top of the page.

Comment: @AzizSaleh It was a simple question :)

Answer (score 4):

You object has to implement [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

```
class MyClass extends ArrayAccess
{
   private $container = array();

   public function offsetSet($offset, $value) 
   {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) 
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) 
    {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) 
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```